# Gluon mobile audio implementation is missing

Tags: java, javafx, audio, gluon-mobile, graalvm-native-image

Because building a native image on windows, ios and android does not support javafx.media, I am using com.gluonhq.attach.audio to realize sound. But I got an issue on linux and windows:

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: ...\.m2\repository\com\gluonhq\attach\audio\4.0.11\audio-4.0.11-desktop.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package com.gluonhq.attach.audio.impl not found in module
```

Has someone an idea? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JavaFX Media/Web with native-image are still not supported on Mac/Windows, but you can use them on Linux. For mobile, you can use Web too, and for Media, Attach has Audio/Video services for iOS and Android (but not for desktop).

Comment: Thank you for helping me again. I was not aware of this fact. For the creation of a cross-platform application it would be nice if there was only one implementation.

Comment: Right, but it is not easy... OpenJFX has already some cross-platform implementation (i.e. for Web), but not for everything related to mobile, so that's where Attach comes in.